# WordPress Max Login Reset

Tags: mysql, wordpress

How do I reset a user's failed logins from the database?

Comment: Which plugin are you using for that? As far as I know a default Wordpress installation doesn't store login attempts in any way.

Comment: I believe that AJweb is correct however in case it is storing them, to remove them, you could just enter the database and do it manually.

Answer (score 3):

With **s2members** if you look in the **wp_options** table there will be a entry similar to `_transient_s2m_ipr_` in there, if you delete this then it should let you back in.

it stores the string -

```
a:1:{s:12:"ip.ip.ip.ip";i:1345820837;}
```

you will also have to delete the timeout entry as well from the table - named `_transient_timeout_s2m_ipr_` or similar this just holds a time in it.

You should then be able to log back into wordpress okay. If it doesnt work the first time then there may be more than one of these you will need to delete from the table.

Comment: Thank you this was perfect!

Answer (score 1):

IF you can't login to s2 member to reset then try:

Create the directory/file **/wp-content/mu-plugins/s2hacks.php** with following code inside:

```
<?php
add_action ("ws_plugin__s2member_before_ip_restrictions_ok", "my_function");
function my_function ($vars = array ())
{
    $vars["__refs"]["restriction"] = false; /* Do NOT impose restrictions. */
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was S2Member. They have a field in their general options that you can turn off... if your admin account isn't the one that's banned!